# c# string[] vs IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#

What should I prefer if I know the number of elements before runtime?

Resharper offers me `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `string[]`?

Comment: You have to work on your question.  It is not at all clear what you want to ask.  Obviously string[] and IEnumerable<string> are two different things/concepts.

Comment: Always use Lists instead of Arrays - that is the rule for me

Comment: @Pabuc - there are scenarios where arrays should be favoured, especially where performance and memory usage is critical.

Comment: @Stephen his question is clear if you're familiar with that ReSharper flag.

Comment: An awesome question this is if ppl understand and just 2 votes? :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to provide this method as an interface to other methods, I would prefer to have the output of your method more generic, hence would go for `IEnumerable<string>`.

Inside a method, if you are trying to instantiate and this is not being passed around to other methods, I would go for `string[]`. <strike>unless I need *deferred execution*</strike>. Although, it doesn't matter which one you use in this case.

Comment: Inside a method it will make no difference and passing in `string[]` vs `IEnumerable<string>` has no effect on deferred execution.

Comment: @Mark: I believe, IEnumerable always allows deferred execution, could you give me an example, to explain "it has no effect"?

Comment: @Mahesh: `string[] foo = {"a", "z", "b"}; var ordered = foo.OrderBy(_ => _)` is a good example: you still get deferred execution, even though you declared your variable as `string[]`.

Comment: @Domenic: Right, we could convert many things to IEnumerable and do the same. But, here the point is just independently choosing between the two.

Comment: @Downvoter: please state the reason for down voting, so that the answer can be improved. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahesh: there is no conversion going on here; it's just the fact that `string[]`, like `List<string>` or many other types, _implements_ `IEnumerable<string>`. You will always get deferred execution for such types, so your claim that declaring a different type has any effect on deferred execution is false.

Comment: The -1 is for the false claim that declared type has an effect on deferred execution.

Comment: @Domenic: Ahh, I got your point. Editing the answer to remove deferred execution part. Thanks, I got carried away.

Comment: @Domeninc: Thanks. Sometimes, I feel pretty stupid when I get carried away, on basic things.

Comment: Incidentally `OrderBy` is exactly *not* deferred execution.

Comment: @Mark: Yup, similarly, `Reverse`.

Comment: @Domenic, funny things how people are reading minds. There is no single mention of declaring anything, just discussion about types, and yup -- the poster is declaring something. Your example with array make no sense, because you used auto declaration, so `ordered` will be IEnumerable. If you would like to get array out of it, you would have to instantiate the collection, like `ToArray` which causes the execution. You simply mixed callee and outcome types.

Answer (score 7):

ReSharper suggests `IEnumerable<string>` *if you are only using methods defined for IEnumerable*. It does so with the idea that, since you clearly do not *need* the value to be typed as array, you might want to hide the exact type from the consumers of (i.e., the code that uses) the value because you might want to change the type in the future.

In most cases, going with the suggestion is the right thing to do. The difference will not be something that you can observe while your program is running; rather, it's in how easily you will find it to make changes to your program in the future.

From the above you can also infer that the whole suggestion/question is meaningless unless the value we are talking about is passed across method boundaries (I don't remember if R# also offers it for a local variable).

Answer (score 4):

If ReSharper suggests you use `IEnumerable<string>` it means you are only using features of that interface and no array specific features. Go with the suggestion of ReSharper and change it.

Answer (score 3):

The actual type should be string[] but depending on the user you may want to expose it as something else.  e.g. `IEnumerable<string> sequence = new string[5]...` In particular if it's something like static readonly, then you should make it a ReadOnlyCollection so the entries can't be modified.

Answer (score 3):

with string[] you can do more you can acces items by index with IEnumerable you have to loop to find specific index

Answer (score 3):

It's probably suggesting this because it's looking for a better [Liskov Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) at this point in your code.  Keep in mind the difference between the declared type and the implementing type.  `IEnumerable<>` isn't an implementation, it's an interface.  You can declare the variable as an `IEnumerable<string>` and build it with a `string[]` since the string array implements `IEnumerable<string>`.

What this does for you is allow you to pass around that string array as a more generic, more abstracted type.  Anything which expects or returns an `IEnumerable<string>` (regardless of implementation, be it `List<string>` or `string[]` or anything else) can then use your string array, without having to worry about the specific implementation you pass it.  As long as it satisfies the interface, it's polymorphic of the correct type.

Keep in mind that this isn't always the way to go.  Sometimes you, as the developer, are *very* concerned with the implementation (perhaps for really fine-grained performance tuning, for example) and don't want to move up to an abstraction.  The decision is up to you.  ReSharper is merely making a suggestion to use an abstraction rather than an implementation in a variable/method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper is likely flagging it for you because you are not returning the least constrained type. If you aren't going to be using access on it by index in the future, I'd go with `IEnumerable` to have less constraint on the method which returns it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your usage later on. If you need to enumare through these elements or sort or compare them later on then I would recommend IEnumerable otherwise go with array.

Answer (score 1):

*I wrote this response for a similar question regarding array or IEnumerable for return values, which was then closed as duplicate before I could post it. I thought the answer might be interesting to some so I post it here.*

The main advantage of IEnumerable over T[] is that IEnumerable (for return values) can be made lazy. Ie it only computes the next element when needed.

Consider the difference between Directory.GetFiles and Directory.EnumerateFiles. GetFiles returns an Array, EnumerateFiles returns IEnumerable. This means that for a directory with two million files the Array will contain two million strings. EnumerateFiles only instansiate the strings as needed saving memory and improving response time.

However, it's not all benefits.

foreach is significantly less efficient on non-arrays (you can see this by disassembling the ILCode).

Array promises more, ie that its length will not change.

Lazy evaluation is not always better, consider the Directory class. The GetFiles implementation will open a find file handle, iterate over all files, close the find file handle and then return results. EnumerateFiles will do nothing until the first find file is requested, then the find file handle is opened and the files iterated, find file handle is closed when the enumerator is disposed. This means that the life-time of the find file handle is controlled by the caller, not the callee. Can be seen as less encapsulation and can give potential runtime errors with locked file handles.

In my humble opinion, I think R# is overzelous in suggestion IEnumerable over arrays especially so for return values (input parameters have less potential drawbacks). What I tend to do when I see a function that returns IEnumerable is a .ToArray in order to avoid potential issues with Lazy evaluation but if the Collection is already an Array this is inefficient.

I like the principle; promise alot, require little. Ie don't require that the input parameters must be arrays (use IEnumerable) but return Array over IEnumerable as Array is a bigger promise.